# How can I consume pdf file from REST web service from within PeopleSoft

Tags: pdf-generation, peoplesoft

We have third party who is sending us pdf file as response to REST based "get" Web service. I am not sure how can I consume this message into PeopleSoft and display the pdf file in browser?

Comment: Please show us how much have you tried so far?

Comment: Not yet!! I am exploring using java class. Will let you know if I ever get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Peoplesoft supports the following function to display external content, e.g.

```
ViewContentURL("http://yourserver/rest/get/123");
```